# They’d been going out for 2 month when they decided to end it

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense

Which sentence is correct, or, at least, the one that sounds natural?

1. They’d been going out for 2 months when they decided to end it.
2. It'd been 2 months since they started going out and decided to end it.
3. They went out for 2 months but decided to end it.
4. They were going out for 2 months when they decided to end it.

Is there any grammar mistake in the question itself, or even in this sentence?

Comment: #2 is the most strange -- has it been two months since they started going out, or two months since they decided to end it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentences 1, 3 and 4 sound natural enough for any speaker. Number one is a bit more elaborate and I think best. Number two makes it sound as if they decided two months ago to end it just as they started going out which it turns out was a good idea.

It'd been 2 months since they started going out and *also* decided to end it.